# ¿Cómo integrar Datatables con ASP.net MVC 3 Serverside usando LinQ y AJAX?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables, linq, post

Esta es una pregunta que responderé más adelante, me aconsejaron que hiciera la pregunta y después diera mi respuesta, así lo hice. Gracias muchachos.

Comment: Bienvenido hermano :D Si la situación es de pregunta-respuesta, te recomiendo que edites la pregunta definiendo el problema y luego publiques la respuesta usando el cuadro de abajo. Saludos y muchas gracias por la ayuda, se valora mucho la intención y el código compartido :D por cierto, recuerda visitar https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que obtengas la 1era medalla y sepas cómo funciona el sitio.

Comment: Gracias hermano.

Comment: de nada bro :D estamos para servir, vamos incrementando el power de los desarrolladores hispanos y de los desarrolladores que entiendan español :D

Answer (score 2):

Esta es la respuesta-ejemplo para ayudar a la comunidad.
Es por que yo en lo personal le batalle mucho viendo otros ejemplos que hacian lo sencillo muy complicado.

En este ejemplo usé solo linQ y la respuesta Request del datatable que va a el controlador.

Este es el constructor de la tabla datatables la petición se hace a traves de ajax.

```
var tablai = $( '#tablaPTAimportation' ).DataTable( {

        "ajax": {
            "url": "/" + NombreCarpetaVirtual + "/PTAI/ListaPTAIServerSide",
            "type": "POST",
            "datatype": "json",
            "data": function ( d )
            {
                //se envian los parametros externos de fecha inicio y final
                d.fechaInicio = $( '#fechaInicio' ).val();
                d.fechaFinal = $( '#fechaFin' ).val();

            }
        },
        //especificacion de las columnas a crear
        "columns": [
            { "data": "PTA_ID", "name": "ID" },
            { "data": "Transaction_Date", "name": "Transaction Date" },
            { "data": "Status_ID", "name": "Status" },
            { "data": "PO_Number", "name": "PO Number" },
            { "data": "Vendor", "name": "Vendor" },
            { "data": "Project_ID", "name": "Project" },
            { "data": "ChargeTo_ID", "name": "Charge To" }
        ],
        //se especifica que es serverside
        "serverSide": "true",
        //que columna ordenara y en que forma
        "order": [1, "desc"],
        //si se mostrara procesando
        "processing": "true",
        //se oculta el pie de pagina de entries
        "bInfo": false,
        //se oculta el filtro general
        "bFilter": false,
        //el mensaje de carga cuando se realice alguna operacion en la tabla
        "language": {

            "processing": "Requering data... please wait"

        }

    } );

    //aqui se renombran las columnas del HTML 
    $( tablai.column( 0 ).header() ).text( 'ID' );
    $( tablai.column( 1 ).header() ).text( 'Transaction Date' );
    $( tablai.column( 2 ).header() ).text( 'Status' );
    $( tablai.column( 3 ).header() ).text( 'PO Number' );
    $( tablai.column( 5 ).header() ).text( 'Project' );
    $( tablai.column( 6 ).header() ).text( 'Charge To' );

    //Datetime picker de bootstrap para la fecha de inicio y de final
    $( '#fechaInicio' ).datetimepicker( {
        allowInputToggle: true,
        defaultDate: '',
        format: 'DD/M/YYYY'
        //esta instruccion actualizara la tabla al ocultarse el pequeño calendario
    } ).on( 'dp.hide', function ( e )
    {
        tablai.draw();

    } );

    $( '#fechaFin' ).datetimepicker( {
        allowInputToggle: true,
        defaultDate: '',
        format: 'DD/M/YYYY'
    } ).on( 'dp.hide', function ( e )
    {
        tablai.draw();

    } );


    //cuentan con un boton que blanquea los inputs de las fechas
    //esta isntruccion reinicializa la tabla despues de borrar los inputs
    $( '#resetearFechas' ).on( 'click', function ()
    {

        $( '#fechaInicio' ).val( '' );
        $( '#fechaFin' ).val( '' );
        tablai.draw();
    } );

    //filtro ydcf plug in de datatables
    yadcf.init( tablai, [{
        column_number: 5,
        filter_type: "text",
        filter_container_id: "ProjectPTA",
        filter_delay: 1000
    }, {
        column_number: 0,
        filter_type: "text",
        filter_container_id: "NumberPTA",
        filter_delay: 1000
    }, {
        column_number: 2,
        filter_type: "text",
        filter_container_id: "StatusPTA",
        filter_delay: 1000
    }] );
```

Este es el método que procesa la petición:

```
 //Este es un metodo post
    [HttpPost]
    //Creamos un metodo el cual dara como resultado un Json este tendra todos los registros de la tabla en cuestion
        //no recibe parametros ya que el Request de datatables es el que lo ofrece.
    public JsonResult ListaPTAIServerSide()
    {


        //se ejecuta la sentencia
        try
        {
            //Parametros de configuracion para la llamada del servidor
            //estos son los parametros que trae el Request del ajax

            //este parametro indica desde que numero debera traer los resultados de la tabla se usa para el paginador
            int start = Convert.ToInt32(Request["start"]);
            //este nos indicara cuantos resultados se mostraran en la tabla de acuerdo a loq ue el usuario eligio en el dropdown de la tabla ejem 10,25,50,100
            int length = Convert.ToInt32(Request["length"]);
            //este parametro indica que columna sera la que se ordene, en este ejemplo yo no lo uso.
            string sortColumnVendor = Request["columns["+Request["order[0][column]"]+"][Vendor]"];
            //este nos dice si sera ascendente o descendente en este ejemplo yo no lo uso
            string sortDirection = Request["order[0][dir]"];
            //este es el search value general como yo uso ydcf filter plugin para datatables yo no lo uso.
            string searchValue = Request["search[value]"];


            //Cuando usas ydcf para habilitar filtros por columna los recibes en el Request señalando el numero index de la columna ademas de los parametros
            //search y value que nos dara el valor del input que ydcf crea
            string sSearch_0 = Request["columns[0][search][value]"];//PTA Number
            string sSearch_2 = Request["columns[2][search][value]"];//estatus
            string sSearch_5 = Request["columns[5][search][value]"];//project
            //en este caso yo necesitaba un Range date para las fechas en filtro de ydcf me daba vacio cada ves que lo invocaba asi que mande mis propios parametros
            //con la fecha de inicio y la fecha de fin
            string sSearch_1 = Request["fechaInicio"];//fechas
            string sSearch_6 = Request["fechaFinal"];


            //normalmente al iniciar la pagina no hay ningun filtro habilitado es por esto que requiero todos los valores asi que asigno fechas extremas
            //solo para la inicializacion
            DateTime fechaInicio = DateTime.ParseExact("01/1/0001", "dd/M/yyyy", null);
            DateTime fechaFin = DateTime.ParseExact("31/12/9999", "dd/M/yyyy", null);

            //valido si viene vacio es que debo mostrar todos los datos
            //en caso contrario convierto la fecha a datetimne
            if (sSearch_1 != "")
            {
                fechaInicio = DateTime.ParseExact(sSearch_1,"dd/M/yyyy",null);


            }
            if (sSearch_6 != ""){
                fechaFin = DateTime.ParseExact(sSearch_6, "dd/M/yyyy", null);

            }
            //En los demas ejemplos que vi en la internet para mvc lo que hacian era requerir completamente todos los datos por ejemplo en mi caso eran mas de 78 mil
            // esto provocaba que en cada peticion tuviese que volver a llenar una lista de 78 mil
            //luego sobre esta lista hacian el filtrado y ya enviaba los 10 requeridos pero en loq ue llenaba la lista tardaba mas de 15 segundos en cargar una sola 
            //peticion de busqueda, esto es prohibitivo en cualquier sistema.

            /*en mi caso lo que hice fue que el motor de base de datos se encargara de todo el proceso y con linQ simplemente hice una consulta con todo el filtrado
             */
             var QRY_SY_Importation_Filtrado = (from i in db.SY_Importation 
                                                //hago los joins requeridos para enviar datos procesados
                                               join s in db.CT_Status on i.Status_ID equals s.Status_ID
                                               join p in db.CT_Projects on i.Project_ID equals p.Project_ID
                                               join c in db.CT_ChargeTo on i.ChargeTo_ID equals c.ChargeTo_ID
                                               //inicio el filtrado Contains() es como LIKE de SQL
                                               where s.Status.Contains(sSearch_2) && p.Project.Contains(sSearch_5) && i.PTA_ID.Contains(sSearch_0)
                                               //Filtrado de rango de fechas
                                               && i.Transaction_Date >= fechaInicio && i.Transaction_Date <= fechaFin

                                               //lo agrego a una lista string basada en el modelo
                                               select new listas.SY_ImportationModListTable()
                                               {

                                                   PTA_ID = i.PTA_ID,
                                                   Transaction_Date = i.Transaction_Date.ToString(),
                                                   Status_ID = s.Status,
                                                   PO_Number = i.PO_Number,
                                                   Vendor = i.Vendor,
                                                   Project_ID = p.Project,
                                                   ChargeTo_ID = c.ChargeTo
                                                   //es muy importante que Skip() lleve antes OrderBy() si no nos dara errores, esta linea es para el pager y para 
                                                   //tomar los que el usuario eligio
                                               }).OrderBy(i => i.Transaction_Date).Skip(start).Take(length);
            //se inicializa la lista 
             List<listas.SY_ImportationModListTable> data = new List<listas.SY_ImportationModListTable>(QRY_SY_Importation_Filtrado);






           //se envia la respuesta 

            var json = Json(new { data = data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });
            // Se amplia el largo de la respuesta json si no dara errores en miles de registros
            json.MaxJsonLength = 500000000;
            return json;



        }
        //cualquier error se cacha y se regresa
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
        }

    }
```

En la red habia un ejemplo con clases y toda la cosa pero era demasiado redundante y hasta cierto punto inentendible, hubo otro ejemploq ue implemente pero era uno que rellenaba una lista y despues filtraba esa lista y enviaba solo 10 resultados pero se tardaba 15 segundos en terminar, con este ejemploa lo mucho en cada petición se va tardar 2 segundos.
Espero no estar infringiendo ninguna regla al ponerlo aqui, de hehco lo iba a poner en el stack en ingles pero pense que seria mejor que mi primer post en español fuera una contribución saludos.
Cualquier pregunta a sus órdenes.